# Augmented virtual reality with GIS capabilities

Tags: software-recommendations, augmented-reality

I want to build an AVR App for any platform or OS with GIS capabilities. Do you know a software for this purpose; I prefer something with less coding.

I found this source http://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/augmented-reality-sdks but it contains too many softwares and I don't know which is for what I want.
An example of what I would like to do you can find in the following website http://moptil.com/

This App should be built by using the camera of a mobile phone or a Tablet. Using this App one can see the real world and some spatial data and general information. My problem is that I don't know what software I should use.

Comment: What do you want to do with AVR?

Comment: I edit the question and add more details

Comment: Don't forget that there is a [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange that can be used when seeking software recommendations.